# Plugin throws ReferenceError when being called

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I wrote a very basic plugin that gets called on blur events, and I have it placed in a file with another that I wrote that works fine.
When I leave an input field, I keep getting an error saying that its undefined and I am not sure why it keeps saying that.

The error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Validation_Required is not defined

my plugin is

```
(function ($) {

    // This one works fine, but is called on a button click
    $.fn.Validation = function (options)...

    // This is the plugin that throws the ReferenceError
    $.fn.Validation_Required = function (e) {
        let me = $('#' + e.target.id);

        if (me[0].value.length > 0) {
            me.css('border', '2px solid green');
        }
        else {
            me.css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
        return;
    }
}(jQuery));
```

the call for the function is

```
$('.required').blur((e) => {
        Validation_Required(e);
});
```

Why is the error being thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
Validation_Required(e);
```

Change to:

```
$(this).Validation_Required(e);
```

Validation_Required is not a global function but a new method added to jQuery. Hence, you need a jQuery object in order to use that function.

```js
(function ($) {

    // This one works fine, but is called on a button click
    $.fn.Validation = function (options) {
    }

    // This is the plugin that throws the ReferenceError
    $.fn.Validation_Required = function (e) {
        console.log('Validation_Required called....');
        return;
        let me = $('#' + e.target.id);

        if (me[0].value.length > 0) {
            me.css('border', '2px solid green');
        }
        else {
            me.css('border', '2px solid red');
        }
        return;
    }
}(jQuery));


$('.required').blur(function (e) {
    $(this).Validation_Required(e);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="required" type="text">
```